# Customize xtable

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I'd like to customize `xtable` for export into LaTeX. I know there are some questions abot `xtable` here, but I couldn't find the specific things I'm looking for.

Here is an example of how my table might look like:

```
my.table <- data.frame(Specifiers=c("","Spec1", "Spec2", "Spec3"),
    Values1 = c("N=10", 1.03, 1.71, 2.25),
    Values2 = c("N=20", 1.32, 1.79, 2.43))
colnames(my.table)[1] <- ""
```

Which creates:

```
         Values1 Values2
1          N=10    N=20
2 Spec1    1.03    1.32
3 Spec2    1.71    1.79
4 Spec3    2.25    2.43
```

In fact, this table is imported from a .csv-file as `data.frame` with `my.table <- read.delim("filename.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)`

Now I create a LaTeX table with `xtable`:

```
latex.tab <- xtable(my.table, caption=c("Stats"))
print(latex.tab, file="Summarystats.tex",
  floating.environment='sidewaystable',
  include.rownames=FALSE,
  booktabs=TRUE,
  latex.environment=NULL)
```

Here is the resulting LaTeX code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
  \toprule
 & Values1 & Values2 \\ 
  \midrule
               N=10  &  N=20 \\
     Spec1  &  1.03  &  1.32 \\
     Spec2  &  1.71  &  1.79 \\
     Spec3  &  2.25  &  2.43 \\

   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Ok, and now this is what I'd like to change:

1) Insert `\midrule` after the second row instead of after the first.
2) Alternating colours of the rows of this table by inserting `\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}` within the `sidewaystable` (or normal `table`) environment.
3) Rotating column names by 45°
4) Insert `\centering` instead of the `center`-environment in cases when I want to center the table.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: (1) can be done manually using `add.to.row`. The others I think you may need to use another tool for. `latex` in **Hmisc** is usually more flexible than `xtable`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need some pre-processing, extra argument passed to `print.xtable` and some post-processing:

```
my.table <- data.frame(Specifiers=c("","Spec1", "Spec2", "Spec3"),
                       Values1 = c("N=10", 1.03, 1.71, 2.25),
                       Values2 = c("N=20", 1.32, 1.79, 2.43))
colnames(my.table)[1] <- ""

# Pre-processing: rotates column names by 45 degrees
head = apply(as.array(names(my.table)), 1, function(x) paste("\\rotatebox{45}{", x, "}"))
head = paste(head, c(rep("&", length(head)-1), "\\\\\n"), collapse="")

latex.tab <- xtable(my.table, caption=c("Stats"))
ltable = print(latex.tab, file="", # File is empty, post-processing needed
      floating.environment='sidewaystable',
      include.rownames=FALSE,
      include.colnames=FALSE, # No colnames
      booktabs=TRUE,
      latex.environment="center", # Or NULL
      # Adds some extra-text after the rows specified in pos.
      # Adds new \midrule and comments old one.
      # Adds pre-processed names of columns
      add.to.row=list(pos=as.list(c(0, 0, 1)), command=as.vector(c(head, "%", "\\midrule\n"))))

# Post-processing: replaces \begin{center} with \centering
ltable = sub("\\begin{center}\n", "\\centering\n", ltable, fixed=TRUE)
ltable = sub("\\end{center}\n", "\n", ltable, fixed=TRUE)

# Post-processing: adds alternating colours
ltable = sub("\\begin{tabular}",
             "\\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}\n\\begin{tabular}",
            ltable, fixed=TRUE)

# Writes output to the file
cat(ltable, file="Summarystats.tex")
```

If you need other tabs environment than `tabular` you can 
1) add new variable:

```
TABULAR = "tabular"
```

2) Pass it's value to `print.xtable` like this:

```
...
tabular.environment=TABULAR,
...
```

3) Change your post-processing for alternating colors:

```
ltable = sub(sprintf("\\begin{%s}", TABULAR),
             sprintf("\\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}\n\\begin{%s}", TABULAR),
             ltable, fixed=TRUE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly substitute the `center` environment anymore. I raised support for the `\centering` command as an issue (#2104) and it was fixed by David Scott a few months ago.

Comment: Hello @redmode, could you please add an xtable solution to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098950/how-to-rotate-a-table-left-margin-name-with-knitr-and-xtable ?