# sweave, xtable, longtable and alternating row colors...problems with `add.to.row`

Tags: r, latex, sweave, longtable

[This existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777586/customize-xtable) covers a way to alternate row colors in a latex table by post-processing the output from `print.xtable()`, but I think it's possible to achieve the same thing by using the `add.to.row` argument of `print.xtable()` as described on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7953), avoiding the need for post-processing, which is nice with Sweave. That answer deals with coloring the background of one specific row, but I think it can be extended to coloring all the odd rows.

The problem I'm running into has to do with the `add.to.row` argument, making the length of list `pos` equal the length of character vector `command`. The help file for `print.xtable()` describes:

> add.to.row: a list of two components. The first component (which should
>             be called 'pos') is a list contains the position of rows on
>             which extra commands should be added at the end, The second
>             component (which should be called 'command') is a character
>             vector of the same length of the first component which
>             contains the command that should be added at the end of the
>             specified rows. Default value is 'NULL', i.e. do not add
>             commands.

when using the longtable environment, you can use this `add.to.row` argument to define the "header" rows of your table that should be printed on every page, like so:

```
library(xtable)
my.df=data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=letters[1:10])
print(xtable(my.data.frame,caption="My Table"),
      tabular.environment="longtable",
      floating=FALSE,
      hline.after=c(-1,nrow(my.data.frame)),
      add.to.row=list(pos=list(0),command="\\hline \\endhead ")
```

I need to keep this functionality, and add the additional functionality that every other row should get the command `\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}`

Sounds simple enough. `pos` should be something like `list=(0,1,3,5,7,9)` and `command` should be something like `c("\\hline \\endhead ","\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}","\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}","\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}","\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}","\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}")`

Of course, I want to take advantage of some built in functions to build the odd-row sequence and the repetition of `"\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}"`, so I thought of:

```
pos=list(0,seq(from=1,to=nrow(my.df),by=2))
```

and

```
command=c("\\hline \\endhead ",
          rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}",length(seq(from=1,to=nrow(my.df),by=2))))
```

my problem is that the `pos` list above evaluates to:

```
> pos
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

which has length 2...it needs to have length 6 in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to flatten out the list.
There may be a prettier way, the following does the trick.

```
pos=list(as.list(c(0,seq(from=1,to=nrow(my.df),by=2))))[[1]]
```

The whole package is then:

```
library(xtable)
my.df=data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=letters[1:10])

print(xtable(my.df,caption="My Table"),
      tabular.environment="longtable",
      floating=FALSE,
      hline.after=c(-1,nrow(my.df)),
      add.to.row=list(
      pos=list(as.list(c(0,seq(from=1,to=nrow(my.df),by=2))))[[1]],
      command=c("\\hline \\endhead ",
      rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}",length(seq(from=1,to=nrow(my.df),by=2)))))
      )
```

which produces

```
% latex table generated in R 2.14.2 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Thu Jan 31 12:52:55 2013
\begin{longtable}{rrl}
  \hline
 & a & b \\ 
  \hline \endhead 1 &   1 & a \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}2 &   2 & b \\ 
  3 &   3 & c \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}4 &   4 & d \\ 
  5 &   5 & e \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}6 &   6 & f \\ 
  7 &   7 & g \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}8 &   8 & h \\ 
  9 &   9 & i \\ 
   \rowcolor[gray]{0.8}10 &  10 & j \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{My Table}
\end{longtable}
```

the formatting of the latex is a little ugly, and since `\rowcolor` is supposed to come *before* the row, even though we specified 1,3,5,9 we get coloring on 2,4,6,8 of the output.