# xtable highlighting: \rowcolor shifted down one row

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632307/sweave-xtable-longtable-and-alternating-row-colors-problems-with-add-to-row) in an attempt to add highlighting to rows of a LaTeX table created by `xtable`. In my version, I want to add highlighting to rows conditional upon column `c` having a value of 1. Here's my `R` code to generate the table.

```
<<example>>=
# create data frame
  my.df=data.frame(a=c(1:10),b=letters[1:10],c=sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=TRUE))

# identify index of rows to highlight
  row.i.1 <- which(my.df$c==1)

print(xtable(my.df),
      only.contents=TRUE,
      include.rownames=FALSE,
      include.colnames=FALSE,
      hline.after=NULL,
      type="latex",
      add.to.row=list(
            pos=list(as.list(row.i.1))[[1]],
            command=rep("\\rowcolor{green!20!white}",
                        length(seq(from=1,to=length(row.i.1),by=1)))),
      sanitize.text.function=identity
      )
@
```

This produces the following table:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Mon Nov 11 23:31:51 2013
   1 & a & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  2 & b & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  3 & c & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  4 & d & 0.00 \\ 
    5 & e & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  6 & f & 0.00 \\ 
    7 & g & 0.00 \\ 
    8 & h & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  9 & i & 0.00 \\ 
   10 & j & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}
```

As you can see, the \rowcolors are shifted down by 1 row. It should be:

```
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  1 & a & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  2 & b & 1.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  3 & c & 1.00 \\ 
    4 & d & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  5 & e & 1.00 \\ 
    6 & f & 0.00 \\ 
    7 & g & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  8 & h & 1.00 \\ 
    9 & i & 0.00 \\ 
   \rowcolor{green!20!white}  10 & j & 1.00 \\
```

What is causing this? I have a few extras in my `print(xtable())` command to fit my situation, but I don't think they matter for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Notice that I substracted one from `pos` values.

```
print(xtable(my.df),
      only.contents=TRUE,
      include.rownames=FALSE,
      include.colnames=FALSE,
      hline.after=NULL,
      type="latex",
      add.to.row=list(
        pos=list(as.list(row.i.1-1))[[1]],
        command=rep("\\rowcolor{green!20!white}",
                    length(seq(from=1,to=length(row.i.1),by=1)))),
      sanitize.text.function=identity
)
```

Comment: thanks, @Roman. it works for me too, but i don't see why the subtraction is needed. but it works, so i will use and be thankful. if anyone sees another approach that works without this fix, i'd be interested to know the answer. but in the meantime, thanks again. gets the job done nicely.

Comment: @EricGreen Maybe your assumption is wrong about the `pos` argument. The positions perhaps denote _after_ which line the `command` is parsed...

Comment: @roman-lustrik You are correct, and an added benefit of using that way of counting is that xtable can put stuff before `\begin{tabular}` (pos = -1), or immediately after `\begin{tabular}` (pos = 0), or immediately after the first row (pos = 1, say a `\toprule` command...).